# Dice Question Values

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, lotteries

Can someone please check my answers? If any are wrong I'll post my working out.

$(a)$ I roll five standard $6$-sided dice, and write down the five values shown. Calculate the
probability of each of the following events.

$(i)$ All five dice show the same value.
$\frac{6}{6^5}$

$(ii)$ The dice give five distinct values.
$\frac{6P5}{6^5} = \frac{6!}{6^5}$

$(iii)$ The dice give five consecutive values (not necessarily in the order rolled).
Only possibilities are ordering $\{\,1,2,3,4,5\,\}$ and $\{\,2,3,4,5,6\,\}$. Ordering is 5! for each, so $\frac{5! \cdot 2}{6^5}$

$(iv)$ Three dice show $x$ and two dice show $y$, for some integers $x\neq y$.
There are $6$ possibilities for $x$ and $5$ possibilities for $y$. To order $(x,x,x,y,y)$ it is $\frac{5!}{2!\cdot3!}$. So, $\frac{30 \cdot \frac{5!}{2!\cdot3!}}{6^5}$

Comment: "*for some integers $x!=y$*"  Do you mean $x\neq y$?

Comment: Your answers are all correct.  Be careful with (iv) and generalizations as that can be tricky.  For added practice, I suggest looking at the question of "*Two dice show $x$ and two dice show $y$ and one die shows $z$ for some integers $x\neq y,x\neq z,y\neq z$.*"

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I mean $≠$

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay I will try that problem in a bit. Good to know my answers are correct. My professor doesn't release solutions to any of the problems unfortunately

Comment: With respect to the 2-2-1 comment of @JMoravitz, consider the overcounting trap of **wrongly** construing $~x=1,~y=2,~z=3~$ to be distinct from $~x=2,~y=1,~z=3.$

Comment: The punchline is that it is easy for the (x,x,x,y,y) case to tell after shuffling things around which the x's were and which the y's were.  If it were the sequence of die rolls $2,1,2,2,1$ it is clear that $x=2$ and $y=1$ since only one of those numbers appeared three times and that number will be $x$.  Compare to the extra problem I posed and trying to decide what sequence of choices led to $1,1,2,2,3$.  Was that $x=1,y=2,z=3$ with $x$'s occupying the first two positions, or was that $x=2,y=1,z=3$ with $x$'s occupying the third and fourth positions?

Comment: To handle this, any time we want some labels to occur the same number of times, let us select those labels *simultaneously*.  Rather than $6$ choices for $x$ and $5$ choices for $y$, let us pick the two numbers used as $\binom{6}{2}$ and using these numbers unambiguously let the smaller of them be used for $x$.  In doing so, the dice result of $1,1,2,2,3$ could *only* have been from $x=1,y=2,z=3$ and we have avoided ambiguity and overcounting.